# Can't find variable: method

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Sorry I am new to react native and es6, right now I am having a problem with my API fetch function.

```
componentDidMount() {
      console.log("here");
      this._onPressButtonGET(0)
    }


  renderList = (data) =>{
    if(data){
      return data.map((item) => {
        return(
          {
            rOrder: item.rOrder,
            title: item.title,
            intro: item.intro,
            url: item.url,
            img: item.img,
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }
}

  async _onPressButtonGET(data) {
    console.log("here1");
    try {
        let response = await fetch(api.novel, method:"GET")
        let json = await response.json()
        console.log("here2");

        let dataList = this.renderList(responseData.data.carousel);

        for (  data = 0 ; data < 5; data++){
          if (dataList[data] == null) break;
          console.log(dataList[i]);
        };

        this.setState({ pValue:data })

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("here3");
        this.setState({ refreshing: false })
        alert(error)
      }
  }
```

alert above give me ReferenceError:Can't find variable: method. The console.log "here 2" is not working. I can successfully fetch data without async/await mehtod, but currently, I kinda need async/await. Please help me with these functions.

```
 _onPressButtonGET(data) {
          fetch(api.novel, {method: "GET"})
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
               let dataList = this.renderList(responseData.data.carousel);
               //console.log(dataList);
               //console.log(dataList[1]);
               //let i = 0;
               for (  data = 0 ; data < 5; data++){
                 if (dataList[data] == null) break;
                 //console.log(dataList[i]);
               };
               console.log("outloop" +data);
               this.setState({ pValue:data })
          })
          .done();

      }
```

I use another function to make this fetch successful, but just not with async/await. Now I am curious how this working? And why the async/await one not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
let response = await fetch(api.novel, method:"GET")
//                                    ^
```

`method` is outside of the quotes, as a variable name, but it was never declared anywhere.

You probably meant to pass an [`init` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) to the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
let response = await fetch(api.novel, { method: "GET" })
//                                    ^ passing an object, notice the { }
```

You can also omit the method type (default is "GET"):

```
let response = await fetch(api.novel)
```

Comment: That fixed my problem! Thank you so much, sir!